# Unity Editor workspace buttons missing icons

Tags: unity

In my Unity Editor, workspace buttons (top toolbar and sceneview) do not show icons

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

OS: Windows 7, Unity Editor: 2021.2.18f1

Comment: same problem here tried 2 version of 2021 , sent bug report

Answer (score 1):

Looks similar to the regression error documented [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/2021-dot-1-ui-buttons-on-the-top-toolbar-are-blank).

The posted workaround is to reset the layout to default.

Alternatively, you could try a different version.

If you can easily reproduce the problem on your version, I encourage you to [submit a bug report](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/206336985-How-do-I-submit-a-bug-report-).